Excel - How to calculate the return value when the lookup value falls between two values in the lookup array
Assume I have this lookup table:



Column A
Column B




60%
10


70%
9


80%
8


90%
0


100%
0


110%
0



And the value I want to match is 65%
I'm trying to find a formula that will give me the number that's in the same ratio between 9 and 10 as 65% is between 60% and 70% (in this case - 9.5)
I tried Vlookup/Xlookup and saw that they can be used to search for the nearest value and getting the "answer" that match that value, however that's not exactly what I need
My next thought was to us a complex set of IF based conditions to determine if the value I'm looking for is between any 2 values in Column A and calculate the ratio myself, but that's error prone and I'd love to use a built in Excel formula if one is available

Is the relationship between A and B linear? Also, is the table sorted? You likely can use FORECAST.LINEAR, using a MATCH beforehand to find the appropriate xs and ys.

=TREND(B1:B2,A1:A2,65%)

added more rows to the table to make it look more like the actual usecase.
I don't think TREND works as I need.
@BigBen - could you explain how that should be done?

=TREND({10;9},{0.6;0.7},0.65) is the same as =FORECAST.LINEAR(0.65,{10;9},{0.6;0.7}).

=LET(
    arr, INDEX(
        Table1,
        MATCH(searchValue, Table1[Column A]) + {0; 1},
        {1, 2}
    ),
    TREND(CHOOSECOLS(arr, 2), CHOOSECOLS(arr, 1), searchValue)
)



Table1 is your data table
MATCH(searchValue, Table1[Column A]) + {0; 1} returns the matched row number which will be the one at or less than searchValue plus the next row as a vertical array
INDEX(Table1,Match ... returns the relevant two rows of the data table; and with the {1,2} argument returns both columns
TREND returns the interpolated value

You could use the FORECAST.LINEAR function instead. It will return the same answer. The differences between the two functions are minimal. You can read about it online.
=LET(
    arr, INDEX(
        Table1,
        MATCH(searchValue, Table1[Column A]) + {0; 1},
        {1, 2}
    ),
    FORECAST.LINEAR(
        searchValue,
        CHOOSECOLS(arr, 2),
        CHOOSECOLS(arr, 1)
    )
)

